# Nest Thermostat wiring for heat pump

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, heat-pump, nest

I am trying to replace my Honeywell Thermostat that is connected to a Honeywell EIM with a Nest Thermostat. I only have a 4 wire (G,B,R and W) ran from the EIM to the thermostat. My understanding is I need to completely bypass the EIM all together. I have a standard 6 wire going from the EIM to the heat pump and another 4 wire from the EIM to the air handler.

I know all R will be wired together. Does the nest need a common wire? (B) If that’s the case, I only have 2 wires left, one for the reversing valve and the other to turn the heat pump on (Y or W?) How do I wire in auxiliary heat (W2) with the white wire then? Picture included. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you run a new thermostat cable from the EIM's location to the thermostat's location?

Comment: I’m not sure. The run is relatively short so it appears it may be possible but I have not investigated to see if it moves easily. I was wondering that I may need to run a new wire. However, the recent HVAC guy out said we could do it over 4 wire and I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: The EIM just looks to be a "wire multiplexer" so you can wire the thermostat with 2 wires instead of a bunch. A compatible thermostat send a complex data signal to the EIM, which demultiplexes the data signal into hard on/off on all the different various control wires, W, G, Y etc.   If you want the Nest to do hard on/off controls of all that stuff, you're gonna need more wires in the walls... an 8-wire thermostat cable would not be overkill.

Comment: Yeah - I ended up just running a new 18/7 wire and everything is all good.